# Autolayout. Set two views vertically with dynamic height

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have a view1 which can have dynamic height depending upon content with in it. Just below that view, I have to show the table view. Top space constraint of tableview is view1 and bottom constraint of tableview is view 3 that has fixed height and stick to the bottom.

The problem is that I can neither set height constraint of view1 nor tableview as top view can be dynamic and tableview have to take remaining height that varies in different device and I am getting error:

"Need constraint for Y position or height" for both view 1 and tableview. Although I have set costraint for y position for all views.

How should I solve this.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a constraint so that the top of your tableview is adjacent to your view 1.
2. Create a constraint for view 1's height.  Doesn't matter what value you pick, just pick something.
3. Create an outlet for your constraint in step 2.
4. You should now be able to programmatically update the constraint in step 3 to have whatever value you really want for the height, and the rest should happen like magic.

4a. You might need to call layoutIfNeeded to make the view redraw and relayout things.